# rewriting URLs with regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex

I wish to transform a querystring using a regular expression replace in C#.

I have a number of defined querystring parameters (i.e. A, B and C).

I wish to transform something like this

```
page.aspx?A=XXX&B=YYY&C=1
```

into:

```
page/XXX/YYYY/true
```

Note that the first two parameters values for A and B are simply concatenated, but the part I'm having trouble with is changing the `C=1` to `true` in the output.

Can this even be done? If the `C=1` part isn't found, I don't want to output anything:

```
page.aspx?A=XXX&B=YYY
```

becomes:

```
page/XXX/YYY
```

I don't think the order of A and B in the source querystring are ever in a different order, but could something be written to cope if B came before A?

I've been trying all sorts.  Crucially, I'd love to know if this can be done, because if not, I'll have to do it another way.

Comment: It's going to be simpler (and clearer) to use ordinary c# code, rather than regexes.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off not using a regular expression.
Try this:

```
            string urlString = "page.aspx?A=XXX&B=YYY&C=1";
            var builder = new System.UriBuilder(urlString);
            // the first character in Query will be a "?"
            string[] queries = builder.Query.Substring(1).Split('&');
```

At this point, you have each query item separated into its own string.  You can use the built-in string methods on each element of the array (like queryies[0].StartsWith()) to identify which string is the "C" query string, and build your path as you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt reply JMarsch! I had thought that this was the route I'd be going down.  I'd just wondered if I could create a single regular expression to do the job, as I could then put it in a config file and make the replacement 'generic' in the C# component.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As Robert H mentions in the comments, you may get better mileage out of String.Replace() than you do with Regex.  What I would do, though, with regex (if you really need it) is split them into three different statements so that you're calling 
`Regex.Replace(yourString, [patern for A=], "page/");` 
`Regex.Replace(yourString, [patern for B=], "/");` 
`Regex.Replace(yourString, [patern for C=], "true");`

If you want to be really clear on what you're doing, call `Regex.Match()` for each pattern first to verify the pattern exists in your input.  Then, if it's missing, you can just skip that replace.

Thus, this should work for you: Note: no error checking done, use "as-is" at own risk

```
string input = "A=xxx&B=yyy&C=1";
string input2 = "A=xxx&B=yyy";

if(Regex.Match(input, "A=").Success) input = Regex.Replace(input, "A=", "page/");
if(Regex.Match(input,@"\&B=").Success) input = Regex.Replace(input, @"\&B=", "/");
if(Regex.Match(input,@"\&C=1").Success) input = Regex.Replace(input, @"\&C=1", "/true");

if(Regex.Match(input2, "A=").Success) input2 = Regex.Replace(input2, "A=", "page/");
if(Regex.Match(input2,@"\&B=").Success) input2 = Regex.Replace(input2, @"\&B=", "/");
if(Regex.Match(input2,@"\&C=1").Success) input2 = Regex.Replace(input2, @"\&C=1", "/true");

Console.WriteLine(input); //Output = page/xxx/yyy/true
Console.WriteLine(input2); //Output = page/xxx/yyy
```

Comment: That's quite interesting.  As I said in my reply to JMarsch, I was hoping to put this stuff in a configuration file, and this seems like a possible way of doing things.

Don't worry - I'll do things at my own risk ;)